# jquery html() does not return changed values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a textbox like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I type something in myTextBox, the value is available with `$("#myTextBox").val()`, but is not represented if i do `$("body").html()`. How can I grab the html string and the updated form value too? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need to store a 'snapshot' of the page at the time when it was submitted to generate a PDF from it.

Comment: When do you get `$("body").html()`?

Comment: Then it should give you the markup with updated value.

Comment: It doesn't, thus I created this question.. Have you even tried it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `.attr()` function.

Example:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

After this you can do the:

```
    $("body").html();
```

This should work.

Comment: I need a way to do this for 'all' input elements on the form.

Comment: The OP will have to go through all inputs and change their value using this, but it should work. +1

Comment: $("body").children().each(function() { $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());});

Comment: I fixed my answer to reflect the way to perform the action on all inputs.

Comment: Note that `this.value` will be faster than `$(this).val()`

Comment: @Sarfraz Unless he has hundreds of inputs on the page, the difference will probably be less than a millisecond.

Comment: I used this and adapted it a little per my application (had to do it for input and textarea elements). Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

```
$('[type=text], textarea').each(function(){ this.defaultValue = this.value; });
$('[type=checkbox], [type=radio]').each(function(){ this.defaultChecked = this.checked; });
$('select option').each(function(){ this.defaultSelected = this.selected; });
```

then

```
$("body").html()
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work well with textarea. But this solution works.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer considering the a form does not contain only input element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-value-input', $(this).val());
});
```

and after that you can get your html

```
var bodyHtml = $('body').html().toString().replace('data-value-input', 'value');
```

and that is it.

Comment: And what if a preset value exists in the HTML on page load? You'll have 2 values then, right?

Comment: +1 for @Senad to counteract a -1, for a solution that is on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Well there is one most simpler way of doing this, by employing the live function on the input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var checker = false;
    $("input").live("change", function() {
        checker = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
        if (checker)
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Long way:

```
  $("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
  });
  $("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).val());
  });
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("checked", true);
  });
  $("input:not(:checked)").each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
  });
  $("select option[selected]").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).removeAttr("selected");
  });
  $("select option:selected").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).attr("selected", true);
  });
```