# How can I get all contents from page including values from inputs with a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would need to be able to copy the whole page I am viewing with a simple button. I have found a way to work this out but unfortunately it does not include the values added to inputs.
here is the fonction selecting everything in between my 2 html tags.

```
function getPageHTML() {
  return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

and then I just simply echo out a button calling the function

```
echo "<button class=\"Button\" onclick=\"console.log(getPageHTML());\">Print all html</button>";
```

this works fine but none of the values of inputs are there?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get all value of your form inputs then write on inline, for example:

```
function getPageHTML() {
    // Apply for all your input
    $('input').attr('value', $('input').val());

    return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to set the value of each input field explicitly.

You can use the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095956/jquery-html-does-not-return-changed-values) for that purpose:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

Then your call to `$("html").html()` will work properly.

Comment: Thanks MasterScrat. Works like a charm :-)  .

Comment: would love to but don't have enough reputation yet :-(  need 15 to vote up