# Saving form value along with form in Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am using jQuery & ajax to save a entire form in session which is being generated.
when I press the search button the

```
onclick="updateContentdata();
```

is called. which is doing following.

```
function updateContentdata() {
    var updateSearchContent = $('#savelistdata').html();
    var rowNumb = rowCount;
    var inFileds = JSON.stringify(field_options);

    //  var inputValue =  $('inptval_' + rowCount).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= $HOMEPAGE_ROOT; ?>/ajax_listuser.php",
        data: {
            rowNum: rowNumb,
            field_options: inFileds,
            html: updateSearchContent
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchusers').submit();
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
}
```

**ajax_listuser.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['html']) && isset($_POST['rowNum'])){

        $_SESSION['searchContent'] = $_POST['html'] ;
        $_SESSION['rowNumber'] = $_POST['rowNum'] ;
        $_SESSION['field_options'] = $_POST['field_options'];

    }
?>
```

Form is being saved in the session but I want to keep form values in the session. but it only keeping the form.

So basically I need

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="inptval_2" name="search_input_value[]" value="71347">
```

instead of

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="inptval_2" name="search_input_value[]">
```

Comment: `rowCount` &&  `field_options` are these global variables ?

Comment: Hello, You should fill the value input with a php variable 
`<input class="form-control" type="text" id="inptval_2" name="search_input_value[]" value="<?php $Your_variable; ?>">`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095956/jquery-html-does-not-return-changed-values

Comment: yes , those are global variable @TismonVarghese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this function first:-

```
function getHtml(div){
  div.find("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is("[type='radio']") || $this.is("[type='checkbox']")) {
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    } else {
        if ($this.is("select")) {
            $this.find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
        } else {
            $this.attr("value", $this.val());
        }
     }
   });    
 return div.html();
}
```

and then modify your funciton:-

```
function updateContentdata() {
var updateSearchContent = getHtml($('#savelistdata'));
var rowNumb = rowCount;
var inFileds = JSON.stringify(field_options);

//  var inputValue =  $('inptval_' + rowCount).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= $HOMEPAGE_ROOT; ?>/ajax_listuser.php",
    data: {
        rowNum: rowNumb,
        field_options: inFileds,
        html: updateSearchContent
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#searchusers').submit();
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to put those values back in the form, since the `value="123"` is not part of the html when someone fills the form. Iterate over the values you have and find the corresponding form-element, and set its value