# Update default value of multiple html elements

Tags: jquery

I have a html report that can be save to a file and reopen.
On reopening the file there is a "Refresh" button to update some info from the DB.

Visualy it does bring in the new values, but on saving the report and reopening it, the old value remain.

On saving I do the following.

```
function saveDocument(){
    var pat_id = $("#pat_id").val();
    var doc_id = $("#doc_id").val();
    var htmlText = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";

    return      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: { pat_id:pat_id, doc_id:doc_id ,htmlText:htmlText},
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == true){ 
                alert("Saved successfully.");
            } else {
                var msg = "The file failed to save specified location bellow. Please check.\r\n";
                var msg = msg + data;
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So my problem lies in that the 4th line

```
var htmlText = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

is not picking the ne values set from the refresh.

Refresh looks as follows.

```
    function getRefresh(){
        var pat_id = $("#pat_id").val();
        var hosp_id = $("#hosp_id").val();
        var unit_id = $("#unit_id").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "refresh.php",
            data: { pat_id:pat_id,
                    hosp_id:hosp_id,
                    unit_id:unit_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);

                $('#dad').val(json.dad);
                $('#dtd').val(json.dtd);
                $('#consResp').val(json.consResp);
                $('#ddd').val(json.ddd);
                $('#disTime').val(json.disTime);
                $('#los').val(json.los);
                $('#transTo').val(json.transTo);
                $('#patName').val(json.patName);
                $('#adNo').val(json.adNo);
                $('#dob').val(json.dob);
                $('#gender').val(json.gender);
                $('#weight').val(json.weight);
                $('#AddressTop').val(json.AddressTop);
                $('#PriDg').val(json.PriDg);
                $('#botPICUCons').val(json.botPICUCons);
                $('#botSpeCons').val(json.botSpeCons);
                $('#gpFullName').val(json.gpFullName);
                $('#gpAddressTop').val(json.gpAddressTop);
                $('#admFrom').val(json.admFrom);
            }
        });
    }
```

If I change a singular input in the report, I update the value as follows.

```
        $("html").on("change","input[type='text'], input[type='date'], input[type='time']", function() {
            isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
            if (isDirty)
                this.defaultValue = this.value;
        });
```

but as for the "Refresh" button, Im not sure how to do the above as a mass assignment.

**This question is not the same as the suggested one** in that Im not trying to update "this". Im trying to update about a dozen values on the AJAX success.

**Workflow**

> 1. Create html document from DB.
>
>    - It opens with the values as currently reflects in DB.
> 2. Now you can Edit the allowed editable fields of the report.
> 3. Click save and it saves the Report.
> 4. Re-Open the created report from the DB. ( saved html file is called )
> 5. Click on "Refresh" to update fields from DB
>
>    - New values where fetched with a AJAX call and now reflect on the opened report in the
>        browser
> 6. Click Save.
>
>    - New imported values are not saved, even though they showed up in the report open in the browser.

Suspicion the the old value might still reflect in the virtual DOM. hence why doing

```
var htmlText = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
```

which get the html representation from the virtual DOM ( i suspect ) does not pass the NEW/REFRESHED values to be saved.

Hope that make more sense.

**Snippet of toolbar with buttons to call the actions**

```
<div class="no-print">
    <div class="buttonBar">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Print" onclick="printMe()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Save" onclick="getPageHTML()">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Refresh" onclick="getRefresh()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `getPageHTML()` snippet

```
    function getPageHTML() {
        saveDocument().then(function(){
            alert("Saved successfully.");
            window.close();
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery html() does not return changed values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095956/jquery-html-does-not-return-changed-values)

Comment: @guyaloni How is this a duplicate??? Im talking about mass assignment. You can see from the last snippet of code where I say "this" works for a SINGULAR change.

Comment: @mome in save function check values pat_id and doc_id

Comment: It has nothing to do with the id's thanks @MuhammadAtif. The problem is that in the view, the value is there, but on saving the virtual DOM does noe contain the correct value, so `$("html").html()` has the old value.

Comment: have you checked value of var json = $.parseJSON(data); ? Are they correct?

Comment: Why are you sending the entire HTML code as data? Are you fetching the data from HTML data in backend?

Comment: @MuhammadAtif. Yes they are. as I said. On refresh the correct values are updated to the view, but the Vitrual DOM I suspect stull has the old values. so if you do as in the mentioned line 4 above, the html contains the un-refreshed or old value

Comment: First you are creating a doc, saving it, then opening it and refreshing it, what does this mean: `Visualy it does bring in the new values`?

Comment: @Sahil, Will explain in a update at the bottom.

Comment: can you post how you call the getRefresh() and if you wait to send it again to the save?

Comment: in other words: do you call the saveDocument() after the getRefresh() completed it's work?

Comment: @GianpaoloDiNino There are two buttons "Refresh" and "Save". So complete separate actions.

Comment: ok sorry, missed last points of the work flow.

Comment: `.val()` doesn't update the `value` attribute in the HTML. You'd have to manually set that.... `.attr("value", val)`

Comment: @tymeJV. cool let me try that.

Comment: @tymeJV. Correct mate. Put it in a answer so I can tic you. out of intrest. is `.val()` only for the retrieval of a value then? And why did it show in the view that the value has changed?

Comment: @morne -- Nope, it's for setting as well - the attribute has no reason to be set tho, unless you're doing something specific, as your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.val()` to set the value won't actually update the `value` attribute - it will simply update the value in the view. If you need the attribute updated, manually set it:

```
.attr("value", val);
```