# get html source code of a page including dynamically created elements by Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Such questions are answered before but still i'm not getting a proper solution.
My approach is to get the html source code of 'body' tag and all of its children(dynamically creating) and then save them in session storage. So that the page can be reload data with the help of this cache.

I've done almose everything, just stucked on getting html source code.

I can get html codes by:

```
console.log($('body').html());
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

where body tag is like:

```
    <body>
    <input type="button" id="btnconsole" value="Get Html">
    <div id="divcontainer" style="background-color:blue; height:100%; width:100%;">
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
    </div>
</body>
```

But i'm not getting the 'value' string of input tag. For better understanding: execute the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btnconsole").on('click',function(){
                    console.log($('body').html());
                    //console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnconsole" value="Get Html">
        <div id="divcontainer" style="background-color:blue; height:100%; width:100%;">
            <input type="text" id="textbox">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now write something in the Textbox and press "Get Html" button. Now check the console. There will be html source but "textbox" value will be not there.

I know we can get input value by `.value` but that will be the patchy solution. I'm looking for some code by which we can get complete source code of body tag including values and attributes of dynamically created/modified elements.

Comment: I wouldn't try to save application state by saving HTML, I'd be looking at keeping the application state in a JS object and then save a serialised version of that object (JSON). Then restore state by recreating HTML from the values in the state object as required.

Comment: @nnnnnn, You got me well, actually my next approach is the same as you said. i'm getting html code to further convert them in JSON by using 'domJSON.min.js'. Would u please explain me what u are telling with the help of an example?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @nnnnnn's comment on the question...

> I wouldn't try to save application state by saving HTML, I'd be looking at keeping the application state in a JS object and then save a serialised version of that object (JSON). Then restore state by recreating HTML from the values in the state object as required.

---

**However**, you can do the following to achieve what you want - it is probably the dodgiest thing i've seen in a while though... (do not recommend)...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnconsole").on('click', function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    });
    console.log($('body').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnconsole" value="Get Html">
<div id="divcontainer" style="background-color:blue; height:100%; width:100%;">
  <input type="text" id="textbox" value="initial">
</div>
```

[jquery html() does not return changed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095956/jquery-html-does-not-return-changed-values)

Comment: Thanks @Zze but as i said I know we can get input value by .value but that will be the patchy solution. My objective is to save the page cache before unload the page and then reload the cache on coming back to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i made it after some efforts...
What i'm using is [domJSON](https://github.com/azaslavsky/domJSON/tree/master/dist)

and

```
var elem =  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var o = domJSON.toJSON(elem);

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a developer but an admin way...
Just open your page in Chrome, open Dev Tools, and click on the pointer button on the Elements tab. Chrome will show you the static HTML source...

Comment: That is exactly what the OP did not want! They wanted dynamic HTML (or, more accurately, an HTML representation of dynamic state of DOM). Please, when answering to old question that have already accepted/upvoted answers, be sure to have new information that were not given in the question or existing answers.