# Get all the html code of the form tag and the values of the textboxes in the form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        var submitbnt = '<input type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit" />';
        var formData = '[{"type":"select","label":"Select","className":"form-control","name":"select-1498804267849","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"option-1"},{"label":"Option 2","value":"option-2","selected":true},{"label":"Option 3","value":"option-3"}]},{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1498804394861","subtype":"text"},{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1498804395129","subtype":"text"}]';
        
        
        formRenderOpts = {
            dataType: 'json',
            formData:formData
        }

       
        $('#mform').formRender(formRenderOpts);
        $('#mform').append(submitbnt);
    

        document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
            var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
            var result = {};
            for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
                result[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }
            console.log($('#mform').formData());
            result = JSON.stringify(result); // just key/ value
            var htmlForm = $('#mform').html(); // Can not get merge values in code
           
        };
    });
```

```html
<h1>Form demo</h1>
<form class="col-md-12" id="mform" style="background-color:white;padding:50px">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-render.min.js"></script>
```

I use the formbuilder of http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io. I render a form. And show that form, then I input the data, and I want to get the html code of that form, I have found many ways but only I can not get the html code of form and values. I only get the html code, but no values. Or I just get the values but no html, I think I will have to manually "mix" the values that I get into the html code. But actually it is very troublesome.

I have a registration form, I want when the user click on the submit button will get all the html code of the form tag, it includes all input, drop-down list, radio, button .. and value already was inputed.

I tried using `$('#myform').html()` to get all the form's code, but it did not get the values that I entered into the input, or radio ...

I want to get something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" class="cusForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to get the html code including the value of the textbox, it is lumped together.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have not solved yet, I use the formbuilder of http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io. I render a form. And show that form, then I input the data, and I want to get the html code of that form, I have found many ways but only I can not get the html code of form and values. I only get the html code, but no values. Or I just get the values but no html, I think I will have to manually "mix" the values that I get into the html code. But actually it is very troublesome.

Comment: Please, Help me

Comment: please Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#myForm').serializeArray()` and `$('#myForm input:text');` to get data and text type input's html of your form.

```js
$("#getTextInputs").on("click", function(){
    console.clear();
    var textInputs = $('#myForm input:text');
    $.each(textInputs, function(){
        $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
        console.log(this);
    })   
})

$("#getFormData").on("click", function(){
    console.clear();
    var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" class="cusForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="getTextInputs" value="Get Text Input Html">
  <input type="button" id="getFormData" value="Get Form Data">
</form>
```

Comment: i think he wants the html (inclunding the values) not only the names/values

Comment: True,I want to get the html code including the value of the textbox, it is lumped together

Comment: @TranAudi Did you try to run snippet above and click Get Form Html button ?

Comment: @TranAudi - Are you facing issue mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095956/jquery-html-does-not-return-changed-values ?

Comment: @TranAudi I have updated snippet, Can you take a look at updated snippet

Comment: @TranAudi Can you create codepen or jsfiddle for your question. And also please specify expected result for your question

Comment: I have clarified my question. Please see help me this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try [`serialize()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY5abChOXUAhWIN48KHQ2VA0QQFgg4MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fserialize%2F&usg=AFQjCNFD3lVbNbUeVzKnxuXghWpIag0Ntg) function of jquery

```js
console.log($('form').serialize())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" class="cusForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to get the html code including the value of the textbox, it is lumped together

Comment: I have clarified my question. Please see help me this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need the html, just in case you need the values of properties that are being post you can check this code, you will get array of the values which are being posted,

```
$(function(){

$('.submit').click(function(){

var result = [];

$('#myForm input').each(function(e,v){

var value = {};
value.property = v.name;
value.value = v.value; 
result.push(value);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));

});

});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jks7afpx/

Comment: I have clarified my question. Please see help me this problem.

Comment: Please create a fiddle so I can help better.

Comment: I have clarified my question. Please see help me this problem